# Regex to pull out numbers from format such as 1+2+2.5 with some additional rules

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to validate numbers in format such as `3.5+1+2+2.5` using regex,  with these rules:

**1)** each number is a multiple of `0.5`

**2)** each number is at least `1`

**3)** only one number is required

For example:

```
`2.5+1`     Validates
`1+2+2.5`   Validates
`1`         Validates
`1.6`       INCORRECT
`1+2+`      INCORRECT
`1+2+2.5+6` Validates
```

I guess its possible? but I am struggling with this faulty pattern:

```
$value = '3.5+1+2+2.5';
if (preg_match('/^(\d(\.5)?)(\+\d(\.5)?)*/', $value)) {
    echo array_sum(explode('+', $value));
}
```

But above pattern seems to be validating everything.

Comment: You could go with `^([1-9]+(\.5)?)(\+(?1))*$`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/nPwnYg/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex needs some small modifications:

- End of string anchor `$`
- Substituting `\d` with `[1-9]`

Using sub-routines a shorter regex would be:

```
^([1-9]+(\.5)?)(\+(?1))*$
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/nPwnYg/1/)

Comment: Your post was very helpful to me and I was able to learn about regex, and alot about *Recursion* support in regex engines, a big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[1-9]+(\.5)?(\+[1-9]+(\.5)?)*$
```